# App for Android to do list the devices on the local network

Tags: android, network-scanner

I often need to use an app on my Android phone to just list the devices on the local network with

- their mac addresses
- ip addresses
- and name, id or manufacturer

I have been using **Fing** for years, but it goes more stupid on every update.  The UI keeps requiring more and more keystrokes just to get to the list and press rescan.

I don't mind paying a modest fee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [PingTools](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pingtools&c=apps) for that type of stuff. Nice collection of tools and all I need, and I believe covers all you need.

Pro (non-ad) version is pretty cheap.

Comment: Comparable feature set: [Network Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myprog.netscan) ;)